# How can I know that node is created or updated?

Tags: 7, nodes, cron

I had configured Drupal 7. I'm going to run cron when a node is saved/updated/deleted. How  I know that node is changed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modules that need to execute code during cron tasks, and for nodes that have been created/updated/delete already implement code to do that. If you need something similar for your own module, you could use the following code.

```
function mymodule_node_insert($node) {
  $queue = DrupalQueue::get('mymodule_cron_queue');
  $queue->createQueue();
  $queue->createItem($node);
}

function mymodule_cron_queue_info() {
  $queues['mymodule_cron_queue'] = array(
    'worker callback' => 'mymodule_cron_worker', 
    'time' => 10,
  );

  return $queues;
}

function mymodule_cron_worker($node) {
  // Code that uses $node.
}
```

With this code, `mymodule_cron_worker()` is called during cron tasks for every node that has been created; if you need to execute code during cron tasks for updated nodes, or deleted nodes, then you need to implement `hook_node_update()`, or `hook_node_delete()`. The code I shown for `hook_node_insert()` is the same code you would use for the other node hooks.

#### References

- [Queue operations](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.queue.inc/group/queue/7)
- [Example: Cron](http://api.drupal.org/api/examples/cron_example!cron_example.module/group/cron_example/7)

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean `trigger` node insert/update/delete events. use:

1. [hook_node_insert](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_insert/7)
2. [hook_node_update](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_update/7)
3. [hook_node_delete](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_delete/7)

And if you need to know status of node (newly created or modified), you can check node's properties: `created` and `changed`